# not correct characters from hieroglf package

Tags: hieroglf

I want some hieroglyphic characters, so I tried to use the `hieroglf` package. The problem is that I don't get the correct characters ([page 7](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/fonts/archaic/hieroglf/hieroglf.pdf)).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}          
\usepackage{hieroglf}

\begin{document}

\HGxxvis

\HCxi

\HGxvii

\end{document}
```

and here is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch the font family:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hieroglf}

\begin{document}
\pmhgfamily
\HGxxvis

\HCxi

\HGxvii

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank's a lot! **A final question:** If I use the `\pmhgfamily`, will the other fonts change? Should I re-switch the font family again?

Comment: Handle is like other fonts switches (e.g. \bfseries): use a group, or use `\textpmhg{\HGxxvis}` which the counterpart to \textbf. See also page 2 of the documentation.

Comment: I use them in a `tikz`'s node (like this `\node[right=4cm of a] (b) {\pmhgfamily \HKi}`). Is that what you mean?

Comment: That should work, a node text is a group, but for one symbol I would probably prefer the \textphmg{...} version.